# Get all Coefficients Belonging to a Factor

Tags: r, lm

I want to automatically determine which coefficients in a `lm` belong to a factor. So assume that I have the following models:

```
d <- data.frame(a = gl(4, 2, 16), b = gl(2, 1, 16), 
                x = runif(16), y = runif(16), Y = runif(16))
l1 <- lm(Y ~ a + b + x + y, data = d)
l2 <- lm(Y ~ x + y, data = d)
```

Then the names of the coefficients of the first model are as follows:

```
names(coef(l1))
# [1] "(Intercept)" "a2"          "a3"          "a4"          "b2"         
# [6] "x"           "y"
```

Now ideally I would like a function which tells me that `a2, a3, a4`and `b2` are coefficients of dummy-coded factors.

For a model which does not contain any factors (like `l2`), the output should be `NULL`.

I had a look at `str(l1)` and I saw that there is (in case of the presence of factors in the model) a slot `xlevels`. I could use `names(l1$xlevels)` to get a list of all factors in the model and then use `grep` on the names of the coefficients:

```
names(coef(l1))[unlist(sapply(names(l1$xlevels), function(.) grep(., names(coef(l1)))))]
# [1] "a2" "a3" "a4" "b2"
```

But this seems to me like a very dirty work-around and won't work as soon as I have similar names in my model:

```
d$a4 <- runif(16)
l3 <- update(l1, . ~ . + a4, data = d)
names(coef(l3))[unlist(sapply(names(l3$xlevels), function(.) grep(., names(coef(l3)))))]
# [1] "a2" "a3" "a4" "a4" "b2"
```

Also, a change of the default contrasts will change the name of the dummy coefficients in my models, so even the most elaborate strategy working on the names of the coefficients probably won't work.

Long story short: how do I get a list of all coefficients which belong to a factor?

Comment: `l3$assign` will be able to show the groups to differentiate between the two `"a4"` coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the fruitful discussion in the comments, I finally came up with this solution. Please note that I slightly changed the desired outcome to return not only coefficients assigned to factors, but also to differentiate whether those belong to a factor main effect, a factor-factor interaction or a factor-variable interaction. I included all the use cases out of the discussion and the output is as expected a proper characterization of the coefficients.

```
getCoefficientType <- function(mod) {
   INTCPT <- "(Intercept)"
   te <- mod$terms
   hasIntercept <- attr(te, "intercept") == 1
   ## factor terms
   predictors <- attr(te, "dataClasses")
   factors <- names(predictors[predictors == "factor"])
   if (hasIntercept) {
      termLabels <- c(INTCPT, attr(te, "term.labels"))
   } else {
      termLabels <- attr(te, "term.labels")
   }
   ## - loop through all terms in the model
   ## - split interactions at ":" into atoms
   ## - check if any of the atoms occurs in the factor list
   types <- sapply(strsplit(termLabels, ":"), function(x) {
      ind <- x %in% factors
      if (length(x) == 1) {
         if (x == INTCPT) {
            "intercept"
         } else if (ind) {
            "factor.main"
         } else {
            "variable.main"
         }
      } else {
         if (all(ind)) {
            "factor.factor.interaction"
         } else if (!any(ind)) {
            "variable.variable.interaction"
         } else {
            "factor.variable.interaction"
         }
      }
   })
   setNames(rep(types, rle(mod$assign)$length), names(coef(mod)))
}

d <- data.frame(a = gl(4, 2, 16), b = gl(2, 1, 16), 
                x = runif(16), y = runif(16), Y = runif(16), a4 = runif(16))
l1 <- lm(Y ~ a + b + x + y, data = d)
l2 <- lm(Y ~ x + y, data = d)
l3 <- update(l1, . ~ . + a4, data = d)
l4 <- update(l3, contrasts = list(a = "contr.poly"))
l5 <- update(l2, . ~ . + a:x + x:y)
l6 <- update(l5, . ~ . - 1)
getCoefficientType(l1)
getCoefficientType(l2)
getCoefficientType(l3)
getCoefficientType(l4)
getCoefficientType(l5)
getCoefficientType(l6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approaches:

**1)** This assumes that any column of the model.matrix containing only zeros and ones belongs to a factor  (except the intercept).  It works for `l1`, `l2` and `l3`, is quite short, does not depend on names (except for the intercept) and does not require fiddling with `lm` object components.  It works for both main effects and interactions since if the main effects are 0/1 then the interactions will be too.  `l4` in the comments is an exammple where the 0/1 assumption does not hold.

```
m <- model.matrix(l1)
all01 <- apply(m == 0 | m == 1, 2, all)
setdiff(names(all01[all01]), "(Intercept)")
## [1] "a2" "a3" "a4" "b2"
```

**2)** This does not use names (except for intercept) and works for `l1`, `l2` and `l3` (and `l4` in the comments).  It does not assume anything about the model matrix but only works for main effects only models.  (The no-intercept case is untested.)

```
cls <- attr(terms(l1), "dataClass")
intercept <- if ("(Intercept)" %in% names(coef(l1))) "" else "+ 0"
fn <- function(nm) names(coef(update(l1, paste(". ~", nm, intercept))))
setdiff(unlist(lapply(names(cls)[cls == "factor"], fn)), "(Intercept)")
```

Comment: +1 Very nice approach! However, the first one relies on the parameterization of the factors and if you change it it won't probably work:

Comment: `l4 <- update(l3, contrasts = list(a = "contr.poly"))` will give you a `model.matrix` where the entries for the associated coeffients are not `0|1`. For the second approach it is a very neat way and it should work for main effects, but for interactions it does not give all factor associated coefficients. This was not mentioned in the original post and it is not a concern for the moment, but may be needed in the future.

Comment: Have added limitations to the discussion in the answer.

Comment: This would work for factor factor interactions (`0|1` invariant holds there) but not for a factor-variable interaction.

Comment: And it would falsely detect a variable which contains just `0s` and `1s` like in `d$false.factor <- sample(0:1, 16, TRUE)`

Comment: The factor-variable and sample examples won't work in (1) -- the sample example will work in (2) -- but are already subsumed under the requirement that the 0/1 columns are factors.